# RedLock.NET and .NET 7 StackExchange Redis Library

Tags: stackexchange.redis, redlock.net

We are using the RedLock.NET and it works fine with .NET 6, but when we upgrade to .NET7, it will not acquire locks.

Has anything changed with the StackExchange Redis Library for this to happen in version.NET 7?